# Javascript Code function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, function

I donot know javascript. I have to do some edits.
I want to know what does the below code does

```
$(window).load(function(){
      setTimeout(function(){
        $("#gmbox div").animate({'top':60},1500,"easeOutElastic");
      },1500);
    });

function trackLink(link, category, action) {
      try {
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'tracklink' ,'click',link.href ]);
        setTimeout('document.location = "' + link.href + '"', 100)
      }catch(err){}
    }

 $('[rel="outbound"]').click(function(e){      
      try {
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent','outbound','click',this.href]);
      }catch(err){}
    });

});
```

Comment: What part of it don't you understand?

Comment: it is a google analytics code

Comment: if you don't know anything about javascript/jquery then probably you should not edit it

Comment: you guys are grumpy.  we were all at this stage once

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Could you tell us where you got this code from? That might help us understand what this code was meant to used for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code with comments added to describe what's going on

```
// wait for the document to finish loading then...
$(window).load(function(){

      // wait a while and then...
      setTimeout(function(){
        // animate out a the div element whose id is 'gmbox' (look up the jquery animate API to understaind the specifics)
        $("#gmbox div").animate({'top':60},1500,"easeOutElastic");
      },1500); // how long to wait (1.5 seconds)
});

// this function isn't actually called anywhere in the code you provided but it could be called from elsewhere
function trackLink(link, category, action) {
      try {
         // tell google analytics that the user clicked on a link
         _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'tracklink' ,'click',link.href ]);
        // wait 0.1 seconds then change the url in the address bar
        setTimeout('document.location = "' + link.href + '"', 100)
      }catch(err){} // don't worry if this code caused an error
    }

// when the user clicks on an element with a rel='outbound' attribute...
 $('[rel="outbound"]').click(function(e){      
      try {
        // report this to google analytics
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent','outbound','click',this.href]);
      }catch(err){} // don't worry if this code caused an error
    });

});
```